# Regex to not allow staring whitespace in string swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I want to create regex thats allows characters numbers and spaces but not at the begning of string , i have created below one but its not working `"^\\S.*[^A-Za-z0-9_ ].*"`.

Swift:

```swift
func containsAllowedCharacters(regex: String?, stringToCheck: String) -> Bool {
    var isValid = false
    if let regex = regex {
        let testString = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
        isValid = testString.evaluate(with: stringToCheck)
    }
    return !isValid
}
```

Comment: It should look like e.g. `let FileNameRegex = #"^(?!\s)[A-Za-z0-9_\s]+$"#`

Comment: Or you could help the user and just remove any leading (or trailing?) spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern, `^\S.*[^A-Za-z0-9_ ].*`, matches start of string with `^`, then matches any non-whitespace char with `\S` (note it matches any punctuation, letters and digits), then matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possbile with `.*`, then matches any char other than an ASCII letter, digit, `_` or space, and then again matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possbile with `.*`.

As you see, all the pattern parts match more than you allow. Also, pay attention you actually *require* at least two chars to be present with this pattern while your code implies you need to support zero length string, too.

You can use

```swift
let FileNameRegex = #"^(?!\s)[A-Za-z0-9_\s]*$"#
```

**NOTE**: As you are using it with `MATCHES` in the `NSPredicate.evaluate`, you do not need the `^` and `$` anchors on both ends since `MATCHES` requires a full string match:

```swift
let FileNameRegex = #"(?!\s)[A-Za-z0-9_\s]*"#
let testString = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
```

Note the use of `#"..."#` notation that makes a raw string literal, where a single backslash is parsed as a literal backslash.

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\s)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location in string that is not immediately followed with a whitespace
- `[A-Za-z0-9_\s]*` - **zero or more** (due to the `*` quantifier) ASCII letters, digits, underscores and whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for lookaheads:

```
^(?! )[ \w]+$
```

`\w` is a short form for `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\u200c\u200d]` (see [**here**](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html) and [**here**](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html) for more information) as it is used very often, but see @Wiktor's comment for a more precise clarification.

Also,see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/WhyJlY/1).

Comment: Well, `\w` is a Unicode aware construct in an ICU regex library, so it is more like `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\u200c\u200d]` ([reference](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html)) in Swift rather than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. thanks for your help  I tried as  "^(?! )[ \\w]+$" as single \ is not allowed in string but its not working

Comment: I have refined regex as let FileNameRegex = "^(?! )([A-Za-z0-9_])" its allowing all special characters  what i am doing wrong, not able to figure out

Comment: Note that [`NSRegularExpression` reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression) that mentions that `\w` matches `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}]` is wrong, see my top comment. It is a bug in their docs.